# Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord just calling Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I know that this type off log is throw when you are doing some heavy processing in the `onReceive()` method of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

But, this is the code of my `onReceive()`, as recommended:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Iniciando classes   
    Intent iLocator = new Intent(context, LocatorService.class);
    context.startService(iLocator);
}
```

The Intent is sent by this method:

```
public void agendarPing() {
    Intent it = new Intent("EXECUTA");
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LocatorService.this, 0,
            it, 0);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 360);

    long tempoReabrir = c.getTimeInMillis();
    AlarmManager reabrir = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    reabrir.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tempoReabrir, p);
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarme agendado com sucesso!");
    stopSelf();
}
```

Why should I had this log?

```
04-24 08:41:40.742: W/ActivityManager(1483): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{40b3f1c0 EXECUTA} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@40bcfef0, started 20008ms ago

04-24 08:41:40.742: W/ActivityManager(1483): Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{40b78208 br.com.contele.locator.LocatorReceiver p=0 o=0 m=0x108000}
```

Comment: i think you should use order broadcast receiver to perform this type of stuff.

Comment: Get rid of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, as that is not relevant for services. You also seem to be using the service in two separate areas (the `BroadcastReceiver` and separately started by `AlarmManager`. Note that the `RTC_WAKEUP` will not be reliable when directly invoking a service.

Comment: @GunjanVerma Why should I use an ordered broadcast?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I took off the flag. What is the problem with `RTC_WAKEUP`?  I need that my service get started also when the phone sleeps..

Comment: "What is the problem with RTC_WAKEUP?" -- `RTC_WAKEUP` is only reliable if your `PendingIntent` is for a `BroadcastReceiver`. Android only guarantees that the device will remain awake long enough for `onReceive()` to be called. After that, the device can fall back asleep. That's why I created `WakefulIntentService`, to help deal with this pattern: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: Wow, if I start my service in `onReceive()` the device can fall back asleep? If the `onReceive()` is guaranted by the System, the `Intent` called inside will be guaranted too, right?

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is useless here, you are starting a `Service` not an `Activity`.

Also, why start the service indirectly ?  Pending Intent alone can start a service on your behalf:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,1001,new Intent(LocatorService.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Pass this Pending Indent to `AlarmManager`.

Comment: I need to start the service this way basically because of the sleep time of the system, as said above